# How to create a mapping to execute python code from Vim?

Tags: python, vim, compilation, shortcut

Here's the steps I follow to execute python code from Vim:

1. I write a python source code using Vim
2. I execute it via `:w !python`

and I'd like a shorter way to execute the code, so I searched the Internet for a shortcut key such as this map:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

and added it to the `_vimrc` file. But when I hit <kbd>F9</kbd>, the following error message appears:

[image]

Here is the relevant text in the image above:

```
python: can't open file ''D:/py2.py'': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
shell returned 2.
```

I have already searched the Internet, but I have not got any result.

I use gVim 8.0 in Windows 10, if that helps.

Comment: Screenshots are evil (especially links to screenshots). Please copy-paste (or manually write) error in your question.

Comment: I added the message manually.@Jérôme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interacting with command-line through vim, the much preferred way would be with exclamation.
Instead of:

```
:exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

Try doing the easy way:

```
:update<bar>!python %<CR>
```

here in the above code:
`update` save file if modified (*preferred*) or can also use `w`.
`<bar>` pipe commands.
`!python %` will run the file as `python filename`.

So basically, put this in your `.vimrc` file, and that'll do it:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :update<bar>!python %<CR>
```

Comment: What should I add to the _vimrc file?Sorry for I can not the ":update<bar>!python %<CR>" ’s meaning you have post.Is this sentence means that I should type :w !python at the bottom of the vim window?

Comment: I am sorry .The former response lost a "understand".

Comment: `autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :update<bar>!python %<CR>`, put this in you .vimrc file, and you are good to go.

Comment: ,Thank you .After adding the code you gave,the cmd returns good result.